# Running a bash script to run a python program gives error: permission denied

Tags: python, bash

Hi I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a list1
declare -a list2

list1=("Hello" "there" "honey")
list2=("More" "strings" "here")

declare -a joined

joined=($(./pytest.py ${list1[@]} ${list2[@]}))
echo ${joined[@]}
```

Following is the python code `pytest.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for i in sys.argv:
print "hi"
```

The error I get is this:

```
./pybash.sh: line 11: ./pytest.py: Permission denied
```

I have used the following to set the permission of the shell script:

```
 chmod +x pybash.sh
```

It still gives me the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Or you could simply call the joined with `python ./pytest.py` instead of simply `pytest.py`

Comment: Also, try adding a shebang line. `#!/usr/bin/env python` so that the shell knows what to execute the script with.

Comment: you need to `chmod +x pytest.py` and add the shebang @dwerner mentions.

Comment: Notice that he's actually got the shebang line already, it's just not properly inside the code block.

Answer (score 3):

Do the chmod on your pytest.py file if you intend to execute it.

Comment: +1 for pointing out which file still needs to have its permission bit set.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps adding :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

at the start of your python script will fix the problem ?

Comment: This fixes a problem that hasn't been exposed yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a shebang (`#!/dir/dir`) to the top of your script will not fix the problem *completely*.

> > You need to change the modification of the file in order to execute.

There are a few different modifications you can make with the `chmod` command, but my favorite is:

```
chmod 755 filename.py
```

755 Allows the owner to read, write, and execute the file. Any other users can only read and execute.

Check out http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php